# Поиск в документе поддокументов MongoDB, через Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Изучаю книгу по стеку MEAN, дошел до одного места и застрял, не хватает знаний, видимо с момента написания книги что-то изменилось или же я не то что-то пишу.
Есть запрос к БД, который должен вернуть один отзыв, отзывы храниться в поддокументах документа, сам документ -  это грубо говоря карточка товара, в которой может быть много отзывов.
Вот как выглядит роутер который обрабатывает запрос:

```
router.get('/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsReadOne);
```

Он забирает из запроса locationid и reviewed и вызывает контроллер, вот его код:

```
module.exports.reviewsReadOne = function(req, res) {
  if (req.params && req.params.locationid && req.params.reviewid){
    Loc
      .findById(req.params.locationid)
      .select('name reviews')
      .exec((err, location)=>{
        let response, review;
        if(!location){
          sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
            "message": "location not found"
          });
          return;
        }else if (err){
          sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
          return;
        }
        if(location.reviews && location.reviews.length > 0){

          review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);          

          if(!review){
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
              "message": "review id not found"
            })
          }else {
            response = {
              location : {
                name: location.name,
                id: req.params.locationid
              },
              review: review
            };
            sendJSONresponse(res, 200, response);
          }
        }else {
          sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
            "message": "No reviews found"
          });
        }

      })
  } else {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
      "message": "Not found location and review id are both required"
    })
  }
```

При вот таком запросе

> http://localhost:3000/api/locations/5c66d32696e86adbe6eff4ee/reviews/5c66d32696e86adbe6eff4eb

Я получаю ответ

> "message": "review id not found"

Потому что в review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid) возвращается null. 
В книге написано, вот что:

> «Mongoose предоставляет также вспомогательный метод для поиска
>   поддокумента по ID. В Mongoose имеется метод, который обрабатывает
>   массив поддокументов, принимая на входе искомый идентификатор. Метод
>   id возвращает единственный подходящий поддокумент и используется
>   следующим образом»

В айдишниках нет ошибок. Вывожу в консоль location.reviews  перед поиском и там все есть:

```
CoreMongooseArray [
  { createdOn: 2019-02-18T19:30:06.942Z,
    author: 'Димка',
    rating: 3,
    id: 5c66d32696e86adbe6eff4eb,
    timestamp: 2017-07-21T21:00:00.000Z,
    reviewText: 'Комментарий о заведении' },
  { createdOn: 2019-02-18T19:30:06.942Z,
    author: 'Петька',
    id: 5c66d32696e86adbe6eff4ec,
    rating: 3,
    timestamp: 2018-05-31T21:00:00.000Z,
    reviewText: 'Еще один комментарий о этом кафе' },
  { createdOn: 2019-02-18T19:30:06.941Z,
    author: 'Олька',
    id: 5c66d32696e86adbe6eff4ed,
    rating: 3,
    timestamp: 2018-06-10T21:00:00.000Z,
    reviewText: 'Снова комментарий для кофейни' },
  _path: 'reviews',
  toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
  _atomics: {},
  _parent: { _id: 5c66d32696e86adbe6eff4ee,
    name: 'CoffeeMax',
    reviews: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  _cast: [Function: _cast],
  _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
  _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
  '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
  hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
  _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
  push: [Function: push],
  nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
  '$pop': [Function: $pop],
  pop: [Function: pop],
  '$shift': [Function: $shift],
  shift: [Function: shift],
  pull: [Function: pull],
  splice: [Function: splice],
  unshift: [Function: unshift],
  sort: [Function: sort],
  addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
  set: [Function: set],
  toObject: [Function: toObject],
  inspect: [Function: inspect],
  indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
  remove: [Function: pull],
  id: [Function: id],
  create: [Function: create],
  notify: [Function: notify],
  isMongooseDocumentArray: true,
  validators: [],
  _schema: DocumentArray {
    casterConstructor:
     { [Function: EmbeddedDocument]
       schema: [Schema],
       '$isArraySubdocument': true,
       events: [EventEmitter],
       _events: undefined,
       _eventsCount: 0,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
       getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
       emit: [Function: emit],
       addListener: [Function: addListener],
       on: [Function: addListener],
       prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
       once: [Function: once],
       prependOnceListener: [Function: prependOnceListener],
       removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
       off: [Function: removeListener],
       removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
       listeners: [Function: listeners],
       rawListeners: [Function: rawListeners],
       listenerCount: [Function: listenerCount],
       eventNames: [Function: eventNames],
       options: [Object],
       path: 'reviews',
       base: [Mongoose],
       '$appliedMethods': true,
       '$appliedHooks': true,
       _middleware: [Kareem] },
    caster:
     { [Function: EmbeddedDocument]
       schema: [Schema],
       '$isArraySubdocument': true,
       events: [EventEmitter],
       _events: undefined,
       _eventsCount: 0,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
       getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
       emit: [Function: emit],
       addListener: [Function: addListener],
       on: [Function: addListener],
       prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
       once: [Function: once],
       prependOnceListener: [Function: prependOnceListener],
       removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
       off: [Function: removeListener],
       removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
       listeners: [Function: listeners],
       rawListeners: [Function: rawListeners],
       listenerCount: [Function: listenerCount],
       eventNames: [Function: eventNames],
       options: [Object],
       path: 'reviews',
       base: [Mongoose],
       '$appliedMethods': true,
       '$appliedHooks': true,
       _middleware: [Kareem] },
    '$isMongooseArray': true,
    path: 'reviews',
    instance: 'Array',
    validators: [],
    getters: [],
    setters: [],
    options: { type: [Array] },
    _index: null,
    defaultValue: [Function],
    schema:
     Schema {
       obj: [Object],
       paths: [Object],
       aliases: {},
       subpaths: {},
       virtuals: [Object],
       singleNestedPaths: {},
       nested: {},
       inherits: {},
       callQueue: [],
       _indexes: [],
       methods: {},
       methodOptions: {},
       statics: {},
       tree: [Object],
       query: {},
       childSchemas: [],
       plugins: [Array],
       '$id': 2,
       s: [Object],
       _userProvidedOptions: {},
       options: [Object],
       '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
       _requiredpaths: [] },
    schemaOptions: {},
    '$isMongooseDocumentArray': true,
    Constructor:
     { [Function: EmbeddedDocument]
       schema: [Schema],
       '$isArraySubdocument': true,
       events: [EventEmitter],
       _events: undefined,
       _eventsCount: 0,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
       getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
       emit: [Function: emit],
       addListener: [Function: addListener],
       on: [Function: addListener],
       prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
       once: [Function: once],
       prependOnceListener: [Function: prependOnceListener],
       removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
       off: [Function: removeListener],
       removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
       listeners: [Function: listeners],
       rawListeners: [Function: rawListeners],
       listenerCount: [Function: listenerCount],
       eventNames: [Function: eventNames],
       options: [Object],
       path: 'reviews',
       base: [Mongoose],
       '$appliedMethods': true,
       '$appliedHooks': true,
       _middleware: [Kareem] } },
  _handlers: { isNew: [Function: notify], save: [Function: notify] } ]
```

Но сам метод  location.reviews.id возвращает null. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Вот скрин БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вопрос не по теме: есть ссылка на книгу?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @Дмытрык Книга называеться "Стек MEAN. Mongo, Express, Angular, Node", Автора - Саймон Холмс. Ну она старовата, там еще AngularJS рассматривается, но мне, как новичку в этих технологиях было интересно

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел, добавлял данные через консоль, как и описано в книге, видать при таком способе вместо _id создался путь id